# Chess analysis over UCI protocol

Tags: chess, uci

I'm working on a chess UI and am trying to implement a game analysis feature by calling UCI engines. For showing analysis of a specific position two things are needed:

1. get the cp value for the move actually played in a particular position
2. get the next best `n` moves with their cp score

I was wondering if it can me done in one command. To my understanding this would take two calls to the engine (after setting the position -- let's say this is `startpos` now, and white started the analyzed game with a2a4) :

1. `go depth 20 searchmoves a2a4` - to get the value for the actual move
2. `go depth 20` - to get the actual best move(s) with cp value

I was hoping that if I `setoption name MultiPv value 4` and after that call `go` with providing a single `searchmoves X` it would return the cp value for `X` and the next 3 moves. That doesn't happen though (with Stockfish at least) but `searchvalue` restricts the search to the move list provided, even if it is only 1 move -- so I only get the value for that move.

Is it possible to get both `1/` and `2/` in one UCI call per design?

Comment: Just set a max multipv equal to the number of legal moves. Then call engine to search and rank all moves. You will get the top x moves you want and at the same time you will get the score of the specific move you want. Besides you also get the rank of that specific move.

Comment: This is only true if that move that was taken is part of the top x moves, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.